# How to remove eval if creating post data from jqgrid colmodel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jslint

Code below is used to create post data from jqGrid colmondel and post it.
It uses eval() since post key / columns names are not known.
How to replace eval() with something better ?

```
function gridValidate(elem, column, entity, eventText) {
    var i,
      row,
      postData = { _column: column, _entity: entity },
      colModel = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'),
      val;

  row = $(elem).closest('tr.jqgrow');
  postData._rowid = row.attr('id');
  for (i = 1; i < colModel.length; i = i + 1) {
            if (colModel[i].edittype !== "textarea") {
                switch (colModel[i].edittype) {
                    case "custom":
                        val = $('#' + postData._rowid + '_' + colModel[i].name).find("input").val();
                        break;

                    default:
                        val = $('#' + postData._rowid + '_' + colModel[i].name).val();
                        break;
                }
                eval('postData.' + colModel[i].name + '=val');
            }
        }
    }
    $.ajax('Grid/Validate', {
        data: postData,
        type: 'POST',
        } );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.` notation and the `[]` notation for getting and setting object properties.

To be specific, `obj.a === obj['a']`.

The `[]` accepts a variable as well if you don't use `'` (or `"`), whereas the `.` notation does not.

So, in your case:

```
postData[colModel[i].name] = val;
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
eval('postData.' + colModel[i].name + '=val');
```

with:

```
postData[colModel[i].name] = val;
```

That should accomplish what you want.